# Thymeleaf: th:each with exclusion of any particular value

Tags: foreach, thymeleaf, each

I was wondering if it was possible to do a th:each with exclussions

I mean... for example... we have three states in our database and model {FREE,RESERVED,TAKEN} (Enum).

And I would like to do a th:each these states except for one (the one which is selected in the Database for a particular object, I don't want to select an already taken option)

Is there something similar to this **th:except** I've just **invented** for this example?

```
<select>
<option th:each="i: ${state}" th:except="${i.RESERVED}" th:text="${i}" th:value="${i}" ></option>
</select>
```

So I could use this in this context:

```
<tr th:each="spot : ${spots}">
  <td th:text="${spot.name}" th:value="${spot.id}"></td>
  <td>
    <select>
      <option th:each="i: ${state}" th:except="${spot.i}" th:text="${i}" th:value="${i}" ></option>
    </select>
  </td>
<tr>
```

I know I could probably do this in the controller, but I'm wondering if there is any "th:thing" I can use for doing this super fast and easy!

Or even a "th:where" which I can place in the same tag than th:each....

Answer (score 2):

You can use "th:unless" for this purpose. Given your example:

```
<tr th:each="spot : ${spots}">
  <td th:text="${spot.name}" th:value="${spot.id}"></td>
  <td>
    <select>
      <option th:each="i: ${state}" th:unless="${spot == i}" th:text="${i}" th:value="${i}" ></option>
    </select>
  </td>
<tr>
```

From your example `${spot.i}` it is not clear what that variable would be so I assumed you wanted to compare the value of `spot` with `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Ops, I had resolved it a week ago and I forgot to comment how I did it.

It was a lot easier than I thought, I can't explain how, but Spring does a lot of things automatically.

This is my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/bajaAnimal")
public String pagBaja(Model model) {

    List<Spot> spotsList = repository.findAllSpotsByState(Status.RESERVED) //IF YOU FIND BY ONE STATUS, IT WILL EXCLUDE IT FROM OPTIONS!
    model.addAttribute("spots", spotsList);

    Status[] statusOptions = Status.values();
    model.addAttribute("statuses", statusOptions );

return "animales/bajaAnimal";
}
```

My HTML:

```
<th:block th:each="spot: ${spots}">
    <select class="form-control" th:name="selectEstado" th:id="selectEstado" required>
        <option value="" selected="selected">Change status</option>
        <th:block th:each="i : ${statuses}">
            <th:block th:if="${i != spot.status}">
                <option th:value="${i}" th:text="${i}"></option>
            </th:block>
        </th:block>
    </select>
</th:block>
```